# Ошибка вывода постов на другой странице (файле) Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Имеется ошибка при выводе постов - дублируются посты в странице где открыт определенный пост, в файле footer.php я добавил следующий фрагмент кода вывода разных постов

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) :
get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/news_single');
else :
get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/news_single', 'none' );
endif;
?>
```

Пример если открыть пост с названием "Автобиография Шекспира", то внизу поста также появляются 3-поста но с одинаковыми названиями "Автобиография Шекспира"

Проблема: дублируются посты
Цель: На странице поста выводить в формате блока также другие посты (новости) а не его дубликат
Помогите в правильно реализации PHP- кода для вывода разных постов внутри страницы поста (новости)

Comment: У вас цикл кончился в контенте. В футере надо новый цикл запускать. https://wp-kama.ru/id_767/3-sposoba-postroeniya-tsiklov-v-wordpress.html

Comment: не получается реализовать

Comment: @KAGGDesign пожалуйста напишите правильный цикл с использованием того кода

Comment: Создайте нормальный вопрос, или отредактируйте этот. Укажите - сколько постов выводить, из какой категории, какие это посты - последние по дате? и т.д.